# managed Socket server component

Tags: .net, performance, sockets, asynchronous

We need to develop a highly salable solution that handles 8000 simultaneous socket connections (from point of sale terminals) and about 1M messages a day. The business logic to handle the messages has already been developed.

We currently investigating the use of Async Sockets and would like to know if anybody has implemented a .NET async socket server that can handle a similar load described above for extended periods of time? not just a POC but in a real life production environment?

Also, do any third party server controls that can handle these requirements exist? I've looked and found ServerFramework http://www.serverframework.com/ and SocketWrench http://www.catalyst.com/products/socketwrench/ but would like to know if anybody has used these components (or others)?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

8000 simultaneous connections really aren't that much. On a modern OS you can open hundreds of thousands of idle connections, even on commodity hardware.

1M messages a day are also not that much by themselves. I can process 10-100k of TCP roundtrips on my desktop PC, so you see that the messages themselves will not cause much load. It is the business logic that will cause load.

You definitely need to use async IO for this. 8000 threads would be far too much. If you actually use async IO and are efficient with your buffers and such, I wouldn't foresee many problems at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there any good sample implementation of using async IO?

Comment: I think you'll find plenty on Google cause it is all the rage now. It is not *that* different from synchronous IO. Just a lot less convenient.

Comment: Are you talking about Asynchronous calls as in BeginReceive/BeginSend or Async IO socket calls using SocketAsyncEventArgs? I know there are plenty of BeginReceive/BeginSend examples but that parttern doesn't perform well and will cause out of memory issues in heavy load environment. Using SocketAsyncEventArgs should solve this but I can only find one SocketAsyncEventArgs http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod

Comment: SocketAsyncEventArgs is used mainly to avoid allocations. Its programming model is awkward however as you cannot use the TPL for this. I recommend that you use BeginReceive/BeginSend and see if you have performance problems (you won't).

Comment: I have a sample BeginReceive/BeginSend example and it seems to be leaking memory. I haven't spent the time to identify where hte memory leak. I figured I will start using the SocketAsyncEventArgs instead. The BeginReceive/Begin send cannot handle more than 1000 simultaneous connections before crashing!

Comment: I have a sample BeginReceive/BeginSend that opens 800 connections and sends one message per connection every 2 seconds. This quickly runs out of memory and crashes as well. This could be happening because I'm not using a BufferManager class and I'm allocating new memory for every new message received which most likely causes the memory to become too fragmented...

Comment: @AmineZegl, you should ask a new question. Looks like your code has a bug, that's all. Or do you see an actual problem with the API?